# Choose file extraction method based on file type - tar.bz2, tar.gz, tar.xz

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a small bash one-liner that downloads a list of archive from various sources. Here's a sample of the file that has the list:

```
http://this-is-url1/url1.tar.gz
http://www.this-is-url2/url2.tar.bz2
http://this-is-url3/url3.tar.bz2
http://this-is-url4/url4.tar.gz
http://this-is-the-last-url/url.tar.xz
```

I download the files using the following:

```
for i in `cat d_list.txt`; do wget $i; done
```

where "d_list", is the name of the text file above. Now, I want to use the same file to extract the files too. To extract the file-name, I've used bash with parameter expansion, like so:

```
for i in `cat d_list.txt`; do echo "${i##*/}" ; done
```

But as you can see, the file compression type are different. I have `bzip2`, `xz-tools` etc already installed so my question is how do I select the correct extraction method for each file?

**Note:** I'm guessing, one method is to extract the last string (which would be either `xz` or `bz2` or `gz`) and then use an `if-condition` to compare and then choose the extraction method best on a string match. Is this correct or is there a simpler method to achieve this?

Comment: Try to see if your tar version has the `-a, --auto-compress` option: `use archive suffix to determine the compression program`. It will handle automatically bz/gz/...

Comment: Also, as I was just pointed out in another post, you could use `wget -i d_list.txt` to download all the archives in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
while read -r f; do
    wget "$f" -O "${f##*/}"
done < d_list.txt
```